# Distributed Components and Class Versioning

Tags: architecture, versioning, distribution

We have a distributed system, in which two components: A and B, communicate by sending to each other some transport object, which is very large and complex.
Currently, the object is simply serialized into the wire by A and is read by B.

Now we are required to support a scenario in which B's version is advanced while A's version stays the same, which means B must have versioning capabilities to be able to process older versions of the communication object.

What are the common ways to do this?
(We use Java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have different versions of the method - one that takes the old version and that `A` uses.

This method can also act as a translator into the new version ([anti-corruption layer](http://thinkddd.com/glossary/anti-corruption-layer/), if you will) and utilise a new method that all new clients should use.

Basically, your `B` should be able to read both versions - internally the best way is to translate the old version to the new one and use that throughout the codebase of `B`.